# Generating a Scala list of random size

Tags: json, scala

I am creating a scala json using :

```
lazy val genDefaultValue: Gen[List[JsonPatch]] = {
listOf(
  genJson("/primary", true),
  genJson("/secondary", true),
  genJson("/fallback", true)
)
}
```

This creates only a random json with one of the item. I am unable to create a list of random size using above 3 list elements. ListSize can be anything between 1 to 3.

genJson is an internal function which creates a Json when passed a path, Gen[T] for expected type.

Comment: Are elements allowed to repeat?  What have you tried?

Comment: If `genJson` generates an instance of `org.scalacheck.Gen[T]`, you can write `lazy val genDefaultvalue = Gen.listOf(Gen.oneOf(genJson("/primary", true), genJson("/secondary", true), genJson("/fallback", true)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is as follows:

1. Reorder the list with `Random.shuffle()` (if you want the order to differ each time).
2. Call `.take(x)` on the (optionally shuffled) list, where x is a random value between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ScalaCheck and `genJson` returns an instance of `Gen[JsonPatch]`, the following code defines a generator for lists of `JsonPatch` instances:

```
lazy val genDefaultvalue =
   Gen.listOf(Gen.oneOf(genJson("/primary", true),
                        genJson("/secondary", true),
                        genJson("/fallback", true)))
```